# Error al compilar al ejecutar

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Buen día.

Al momento de compilar y ejecutar la app, cuando se abre el navegador me aparece un error de 400 (Bad Request)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta pregunta necesita mas informacion, sobre todo codigo fuente, es mala practica preguntar solo pegando imagenes, lo mas problable es que sea cerrada por esta razon.

Comment: No puse código por qué no supe la razón del error, de la nada me empezó a aparecer.

Comment: Que cambiaste? que dice el error completo? que dice la ide, donde esta tambien el error? necesitamos ver el error.. esto no es el error.. esto dice que tenes un error...

Comment: Corre la aplicacion con F10 y vete paso a posa para que veas donde truena, si estas utilizando iis express cambiate a iis o viceversa eso te podria dar una idea de cual es el error.

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es publicar tu app es iis y revisar si te sale error alli tmb.

Suena algun tipo de error relaciondo con la configuracion del server, ya sea porque  no tienes el runtime correspondiente al framework o configuracion dentro del web.config o appsettings, dificil llegar a una conclusion sin tener tu mismo ambiente